# Face detection for C# in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, face-recognition

I'm looking for a specific form of facial recognition. I want to detect where all the faces are located (and that's all) on an image of students in a class-picture.

So in other words, I'm not trying to compare two faces and see if they match either.

How can I do this in C#? I can't seem to find any open-source projects on NuGet regarding this, and I've looked on CodePlex too.

Comment: Maybe take a look at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/705429/1133212

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that [Face](http://face.com) has retired since it was purchased by Facebook, I use [Sky Biometry](http://www.skybiometry.com/), which has a C# .NET API and is free.

It's cloud based and obviously requires an Internet connection, but who cares.

Answer (score 3):

My personal preference for any Computer Vision related needs is to use http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/ , however, it isn't natively made for C#.

However, after a quick Google search, I found http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page which says "Emgu CV is a cross platform .Net wrapper to the Intel OpenCV image processing library. `Allowing OpenCV functions to be called from .NET compatible languages such as C#`, VB, VC++, IronPython etc. The wrapper can be compiled in Mono and run on Linux / Mac OS X."

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking **FaceRecognition.Net** (https://github.com/takuya-takeuchi/FaceRecognitionDotNet) that is base on **Face Recognition** (https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition) that is implemented in Python. Both are Open Source with MIT license.

Another option is **Cognitive Services – Face** that is from Microsoft and you can use it from Azure directly or from a local Docker. Here you can find more about it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime there are more libraries and approaches available. Based on deep learning and ONNX, these projects might be worth to take a look at (both MIT-licensed):

- [FaceONNX](https://github.com/FaceONNX/FaceONNX) ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FaceONNX/)), which is based on `System.Drawing` and includes models provided by the author
- [FaceAiSharp](https://github.com/georg-jung/FaceAiSharp) ([NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FaceAiSharp.Bundle/)) is based on [ImageSharp](https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp) and uses publicly available state-of-the-art models for face recognition ([ArcFace](https://github.com/onnx/models/tree/main/vision/body_analysis/arcface)) and face detection (InsightFace's [SCRFD](https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface/tree/master/detection/scrfd)). There's also an [interactive tutorial](https://github.com/georg-jung/explain-face-rec) with hands-on examples available.

Finding all the faces in a group photo could be done like this using FaceAiSharp:

1. `dotnet new console`
2. ```bash
   dotnet add package FaceAiSharp.Bundle
   dotnet add package Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime
   ```
3. Edit `Program.cs`:

```cs
using FaceAiSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats;

// adjust these lines to load your own image
using var hc = new HttpClient();
var groupPhoto = await hc.GetByteArrayAsync(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/georg-jung/FaceAiSharp/master/examples/obama_family.jpg");
var img = Image.Load<Rgb24>(groupPhoto);

var det = FaceAiSharpBundleFactory.CreateFaceDetector();
var faces = det.DetectFaces(img);
foreach (var face in faces)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Found a face with confidence {face.Confidence}: {face.Box}");
}
```

4. `dotnet run`

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of FaceAiSharp. Feel free to open an issue if something doesn't work for you or could be improved.